# Jaxws working in Websphere 7.0.0.23 failing in 7.0.0.25

Tags: web-services, websphere

Our project is a jax-ws webservices project and we recently upgraded the Websphere version 7.0.0.23 to 7.0.0.25. The services are working fine in the websphere 7.0.0.23. But after upgrade to 7.0.0.25, the services are not working.

We configured the service endpoint class(which does not extend HttpServlet) in the web.xml for the wsdl URL which works fine in 7.0.0.23 but when we deploy the same application in 7.0.0.25 it is throwing service endpoint class is not a servlet class.

1. Why the 7.0.0.23 is not throwing "Not a servlet class" error like 7.0.0.25? How can i make it work in 7.0.0.25?
2. As mentioned in JSR 181, i configured the wsdl URL through annotations(removed config from web.xml) and that was working fine in 7.0.0.23 but not working in 7.0.0.25. How can i fix this? I also tried the property "com.ibm.websphere.webservices.UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy =true" in the JVM property. But still it is not working.